# How to style element content in Svelte?

Tags: frontend, svelte, svelte-3

```html
<style>

  color: red;

</style>

Some html content!
```

this code does not work. In the Angular framework it can be done by using the `:host` selector. `:global` can't help in my case, because I just want to style the component, where these styles are written.
How can I do this in Svelte?
Thank you

PS. I'm pretty new in Svelte :)

Comment: FYI: `:global` can't help in my case, because I just want to style the component, where these styles are written

Comment: Why don't you use the style on the top most selector in the component? Let's say it is a section, then it should work with ```section { color: red }```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
  .hello {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class='hello'>Hello world</style>
```

This will style all elements with the `hello` class and *only* in this component.

Now if we do something like this

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import A from './A.svelte'
    import B from './B.svelte'
</script>

<div>
    <A/>
    <B/>
</div>
```

A.svelte

```
Hello
```

B.svelte

```
world
```

then svelte renders that as

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

And there's no way to define a selector to style only "Hello" but not "word". The documentation also mentions that it need something to attach a class to:

> CSS inside a  block will be scoped to that component.
>
> This works by adding a class to affected elements, which is based on a hash of the component styles (e.g. svelte-123xyz).

Comment: Angular has the `:host` selector, but Svelte not. Thats most likely because svelte allows multiple root elements in a single component.